# Remove checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I am making a To-do list, where I want to be able to add new tasks, and delete tasks that are checked off. However, it seems my function just deletes **all** tasks, not just the ones that are checked off. Neither does it seem to allow new tasks to be added.

html:

```
<h1 id="title"> To-do list</h1>
<div id="task_area">
</div>
<input type="text" id="putin"></input>
<button id="add">add</button>
```

javascript:

```
<button id="clear">Clear completed tasks</button>

var tasks = document.getElementById("task_area")
var new_task = document.getElementById("add")
var clear = document.getElementById("clear")

new_task.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var putin = document.getElementById("putin")

    var input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = "checkbox"

    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(putin.value))

    task_area.appendChild(input)
    task_area.appendChild(label)


})

clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < task_area.children.length; i++) {
        if (task_area.children[i].checked === true) {

            task_area.remove(tasks.children[i])
        }

    }


})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4coxL3um/

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove Enjoy the face palm you will give yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) removes the element you are calling it from, and doesn't take an argument for what to remove. The following:

```
task_area.remove(tasks.children[i])
```

should be

```
tasks.children[i].remove()
```

**EDIT:** As Mononess commented below, this will only remove the checkboxes and not the labels. While you could delete both using Jayesh Goyani's answer below, it's probably better that each input/label pair be wrapped in a single div or span for easier management.

Comment: Do not forget to remove the labels as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. Below code will help you to remove selected checkbox with label.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="title">To-do list</h1>
    <div id="task_area">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="putin" />
    <button id="add">add</button>

    <button id="clear">Clear completed tasks</button>
    <script>

        var tasks = document.getElementById("task_area")
        var new_task = document.getElementById("add")
        var clear = document.getElementById("clear")

        new_task.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var putin = document.getElementById("putin")

            var input = document.createElement('input')
            input.type = "checkbox"

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(putin.value))

            task_area.appendChild(input)
            task_area.appendChild(label)

            //document.getElementById("task_area").innerHTML = putin.value
        })

        clear.addEventListener("click", function () {
            for (i = 0; i < task_area.children.length; i++) {
                if (task_area.children[i].checked === true) {
                    tasks.children[i].nextSibling.remove();
                    tasks.children[i].remove();

                }

            }
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

Please let me know if any concern.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't seems to remove anything at all. Does it use jQuery?

Comment: My apologies yes I have used jquery. I have updated my above code snippet. (which was used pure javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an event listener to each child of task_area that calls the below function. Haven't gotten a chance to test it out, and may not fulfill all of your requirements, but should get the job done.

```
function removeClicked() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: What event should I use as trigger? Where in the code would this be implemented?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < task_area.children.length; i++) { task_area.children[i].addEventListener("click", removeClicked); }

You would probably be better off setting var children = task_area.children and then iterating through the children array. If I'm not mistaken, otherwise you're collecting the children of task area on each iteration which is slow and inefficient, and may not work as expected.